# How precise is R?

Tags: r

In order to empirically demonstrate a theoretical result, I am currently computing inner products in high-dimensional spaces, that is for some `f(x)` and `f(y)` I am computing `sum(f(x)*f(y))`. Unfortunately, something is going wrong and the inner products I get are much smaller than expected.

Now `f` is a function that does a few multiplications and divisions to arrive at `f(x)`, and `f(x)` has entries of order `e-12`. Is it possible that `R` makes mistakes because the numbers are so small?

Comment: the precision will depend on the architecture you are using. if on 64-bit, its 2^-52. check on `.Machine$double.eps` to see your precision. anyway, if the numbers are too small and if positive, work in the log scale.

Comment: I have precision `2.220446e-16`

Comment: But thanks for the advice with the log scale

Comment: Then you are working on a 64 bit. Meaning it will correctly work with numbers as low as 2^-52.

Comment: @onyambu:  All versions of R use the same precision for final results:  64 bit floating point values, 32 bit integers.  The 64 bit builds allow for bigger vectors, not more precision.  There can be slight differences in intermediate results because some compilers use higher precision for intermediate results, e.g. 80 bits, but R never stores those.  Some packages do their own arithmetic using vectors of numbers for each value to allow for much higher precision.

Answer (score 2):

In a calculation like `sum(x)`, the results depend a lot on the values in `x`.  If all values are the same sign, you would get errors on the order of `1e-15` times the sum.  If some are positive and some are negative, your errors could be as large as `1e-15` times the sum of the absolute values.